# mysql function if/else

Tags: mysql

I have a function that returns a date string.  I need this because I can't use a variable in a view, but I can use a function that returns a variable that I set ahead of time...

So I got all that working, but then I decided that if that I wanted it to return the current date if no date variable was set.  I thought the code below wold work, but I get syntax errors...

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `cc`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ox_date`$$

CREATE  FUNCTION `ox_date`() RETURNS CHAR(50) CHARSET latin1
DECLARE ox VARCHAR(20)
IF @oxdate <1 THEN SET ox = CURDATE$$
ELSE SET ox = @oxdate$$

RETURN ox $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried isnull on that first if, but it wasn't any help.

Comment: slightly modified, but still fails...
DELIMITER $$

USE `cc`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ox_date`$$

CREATE  FUNCTION `ox_date`() RETURNS CHAR(50) CHARSET latin1
DECLARE ox VARCHAR(20)$$
IF @oxdate <1 THEN SET ox = CURDATE()$$
ELSE SET ox = @oxdate$$
END IF$$
RETURN ox $$

DELIMITER ;



............
(0 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

(0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s))
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:01:061
Total Time     : 00:00:01:061

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to fiddle with the delimiter?  For simple logic prefer the IF function to the IF statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ox_date`( )
RETURNS CHAR(50) CHARSET latin1
RETURN IF(@oxdate < 1 OR @oxdate IS NULL, CURDATE(),@oxdate)
```

Else

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `cc`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ox_date`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `ox_date`( )
RETURNS CHAR(50) CHARSET latin1
RETURN IF(@oxdate < 1 OR @oxdate IS NULL, CURDATE(),@oxdate)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but here are a few of things I see.

First, you've got

```
DELIMITER $$
```

and then use it in the function itself.  That DELIMITER line allows you to use the semicolons within the body of the function.  Otherwise the ';' would end the CREATE FUNCTION statement prematurely.

Also, the line

```
DECLARE ox varchar(20)
```

is missing a semicolon at the end.

And then you're missing the

```
END IF;
```

after the else condition.

Also what about the BEGIN END$$ wrapped around the function's definition?

I'd expect a stored function to generally take the form:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `testdb`.MyFunc$$
CREATE FUNCTION `testdb`.`MyFunc` () RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE someVar varchar(20);
   # some stuff
   RETURN something;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Modifying the guts of the function to suit your needs and setting the return type as appropriate.

Anyway, I'm not an expert but that is what I see and hope that helps.